# docker container does not allocates the port

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to place my simple REST Api (built on asp.net core) into docker container.

I have the following docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["/", "SimpleApp.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SimpleApp.Api/SimpleApp.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SimpleApp.Api"
RUN dotnet build "SimpleApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SimpleApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SimpleApp.Api.dll"]
```

I can successfully build an image from this file, but when I run the container I can't, for example, call none of the URLs + I have swagger on top of my API, so it should show me a page but it doesn't.

```
docker run -d --name "mySimpleContainer" "MySimpleApp:latest" --ports 5000:80
```

The url like `localhost:5000` doesn't work so firstly I checked the logs:

```
........
2019-02-02 13:37:17.3635||DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Loaded hosting startup assembly SimpleApp.Api   
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

looks good to me.  Secondary, I checked if 5000 is busy or not... and suddenly it's not!!!
to check the port I used `netstat -an | find ":5000"`

Does anyone know where I failed?

Comment: Docker-specific options like `--ports` need to come before the image name.  You're passing `--ports 5000:80` as the command to run; Docker isn't handling it.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze!!! OMG feel my self idiot, spent the whole day on this! :(